# HTML5 Canvas image rotation with dynamic values and images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have the following code -

```
for(var i = 0; i < treesLength; i++){
    var tmpTree = trees[i];
    tmpTreeX = 1+Math.random()*($("#gameBoard").width()-95);
    tmpTreeY = 1+Math.random()*($("#gameBoard").height()-90);
    var imgTreeFile = new Image();
    imgTreeFile.onload = function() {
        context.save();
        context.translate(tmpTreeX,tmpTreeY);
        context.rotate(47 * Math.PI / 180);
        context.translate(-tmpTreeX,-tmpTreeY);
        context.drawImage(imgTreeFile, tmpTreeX, tmpTreeY);
        context.restore();
    };
    imgTreeFile.src = 'img/tree.png';
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to add `'n'` amount of images to the canvas (That happen to be trees) I want to rotate the images a random amount of radians. Currently just to get it working I have set this number rather than randomly generate the radians.

If I do no try to rotate the images, I successfully get all the images in the loop randomly placed throughout the canvas. When I try to rotate I just get all of the images in the same place with no rotation.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, my searching has only left me frustrated as I "appear" to be doing it correctly (Clearly I am not!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a quick test here there doesn't seem to be an issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ7MQ/

But I do notice two weird things about your code:

1. `.width()` and not `.width` seems weird, but maybe thats a jQuery thing? it should be `canvas.width` in any case.
2. You are **using a loop variable inside of code called asynchronously**, which is 99% likely your problem. I highly recommend that you refactor your code so that all the images are loaded before the loop ever happens. If they are all the same image, that makes this very easy:

   ```
   var imgTreeFile = new Image();
   imgTreeFile.onload = function() {
   for(var i = 0; i < treesLength; i++){
       var tmpTree = trees[i];
       tmpTreeX = 1+Math.random()*($("#gameBoard").width()-95);
       tmpTreeY = 1+Math.random()*($("#gameBoard").height()-90);
       context.save();
       context.translate(tmpTreeX,tmpTreeY);
       context.rotate(47 * Math.PI / 180);
       context.translate(-tmpTreeX,-tmpTreeY);
       context.drawImage(imgTreeFile, tmpTreeX, tmpTreeY);
       context.restore();
     }
   };
   imgTreeFile.src = 'img/tree.png';
   ```

Comment: Yes the width() & height() are from jQuery, forgot to mention I was using this.this has worked thank you!